# The column was not found in the IDataRecord being evaluated

Tags: c#

I am getting this error in a client machine, but same code (C# and stored procedure in SQL) work just fine on my local machine.

> The column code was not found in the IDataRecord being evaluated. This might indicate that the accessor was created with the wrong mappings.

Ref to below code - we are calling a stored procedure which have no output variable declared and returns a integer using return keyword

- `ReturnEntity` object has two fields `Code` and `Message
- `UploadCount` is returning some record to `returnEntityList` which does not have a code field.

Code:

```
IEnumerable<ReturnEntity> returnEntityList = await sampleProvider.UploadCount(Xml);

if (returnEntityList.Count() > 0)
{
    ReturnEntity returnEntity = returnEntityList.FirstOrDefault<ReturnEntity>();
    ReturnModel returnModel = new ReturnModel(returnEntity.code, returnEntity.message);
    return returnModel.message;
}
```

Please help me understand why this issue occurs on client machine and not on Local. And what might fix this issue ...

Comment: Is it possible the two instances are configured differently? Could they be hitting different databases—dev vs. prod, or something?

Comment: Yes, both instance are different, but same SP script is executed on both databases

Comment: I assume you have verified that the stored procedures are identical in each database, and that they return the same fields, including the elusive `code` field?